# Macro in excel to implement a "+" button for N items. how to create only one macro but increment all items individually?

Tags: excel, vba

I created an macro in excel and associated it to a button. Basically, the macro implements a "+" button, which, as the name suggests, increments a counter variable in a cell (say the cell is B1). For instance, if I click twice on the button, B1 stores the value 2, and so on.

I have a longer list of items for which I need this "+" button (N items -> N buttons to increment the items individually). Is there a solution to not create a macro for all N items?

EDIT:

This is how my macro currently looks like:

```
Sub add_1()
    Range("B1").Value = Range("B1").Value + 1
End Sub
```

I launch this macro from a button in cell "A1". I also want to have a button in "A2", which increments the value in cell "B2", and so on.

Comment: You want to just add +1 to every cell in a range and every time you hit the one button, increment all of the cells in said range or is there another condition (I'm thinking if everything gets the same value, then you can just give the range the value of the first incremented value)? Can we see your code so we can know what to adjust?

Comment: Is it feasible for the user to just go to the cell needing the increment before clicking the button?

Comment: When you click a CommandButton this invokes the Click event for the specific button. Detailed info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/click-event) from MS. You can write one macro and call it from the Click event with a parameter of the CommandButton. (e.g. an ID name, or the Cell.Address)

Comment: What do you mean by "list of items for which I need this "+" button "? Is there any relation between a changed cell and a specific such "Item"? Based on what should the required "solution" to identify what such "item" to be incremented?

Comment: @bugdrown No, the user is not supposed to click on a different cell first.

Comment: @Notus_Panda I edited my question and showed the code for one specific button.

Comment: Since you did not answer my clarification question related to "list of items", should I deduce that this list represents the B:B column filled with data? If so, do you want incrementing all that range at a button press, or based on some specific logic?

Comment: If I understood the question, and that's a big IF, you could create as many command buttons as you wanted and use a single macro for all of them, then within your module you can get the command button name and use that name in a Case statement or IF/Then to add whatever value the command button refers to,...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets say you have headers in row 1 and you want your plus-button in column C, then the following code will help you.

```
Option Explicit

Sub add_buttons()
Dim btn As Button
Dim i As Long, last As Long
Dim rng As Range
last = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveSheet.Buttons.Delete
For i = 2 To last
    If Cells(i, 2) <> "" Then
        Set rng = Cells(i, 3)
        Set btn = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(rng.Left, rng.Top, rng.Width, rng.Height)
        With btn
            .OnAction = "btn_plus"
            .Caption = "+"
            .Name = "btn_plus_" & i
        End With
    Else
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub btn_plus()
Dim i As Long
If Left(Application.Caller, 8) = "btn_plus" Then
    i = CInt(Mid(Application.Caller, InStrRev(Application.Caller, "_") + 1))
    Cells(i, 2) = Cells(i, 2) + 1
End If
End Sub
```

The first sub add_buttons add buttons next to every value in column B. The second sub btn_plus, adds +1 to the cell next to the button that is clicked on.

Comment: Not sure I agree with deleting all the buttons of the activesheet (user might have a "update materfile" button or something similar) but other than that, it looks good.

Comment: That is what I was looking for and gives me a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I have created this macro:

```
Sub Increase()
ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value + 1
End Sub
```

... and added a commandbutton, launching this macro, when clicked.

I selected cell "B2", entered the number 5 and clicked two times.
Then I selected cell "B3" and clicked two times:

Resulting screenshot:

[image]